# Unable to align JLabel component in JPanel to the left of the JPanel it is in

Tags: java, jlabel, windowbuilder, swingbuilder, applicationwindow

No matter how I set my Bounds for my JLabel, it is always in the same spot. I am using the Window Builder Swing Designer Application window. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Restaurants {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Restaurants window = new Restaurants();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
     public Restaurants() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 689);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 12));
    panel.setBounds(10, 143, 572, 258);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    JLabel label= new JLabel("Chicken Burger Meal");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    label.setBounds(21,70,173,29);
    panel.add(label);

    JLabel lblChickenBurger = new JLabel("Chicken Burger");
    lblChickenBurger.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblChickenBurger.setBounds(21,22,173,29);
    panel.add(lblChickenBurger);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 12));
    panel_1.setBounds(592, 143, 401, 259);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);

    JPanel panel_2=new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0), 12));
    panel_2.setBounds(10,412,572,228);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_2);

    JPanel panel_3=new JPanel();
    panel_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0),12));
    panel_3.setBounds(592,411,401,228);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_3);

    JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
    panel_4.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 12));
    panel_4.setBounds(1003, 174, 401, 465);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_4);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Loan Management System");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 60));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(160, 49, 849, 96);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
}
```

}

What do you think is wrong? I have sorted through all possible strategies that I can think of , but none of the strategies seems to yield any type of viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the arguments passed into the `setBounds()` method seems to be working for me with your code. Specifically which JPanel are you trying to move?

I would try looking at the GridLayout layout manager for what you're trying to do:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most appropriate way is to NOT use absolute positioning - use the appropriate layout manager(s). Attempting to use absolute positioning is fraught with problem, especially if you port to a different platform that has a different screen size, or pixel size, or default font, or any of dozens of other things. And changing font or label strings, or adding/removing components, will be a nightmare.

JPanel itsepf does not pay any attention to a component's size of (x,y) - it relies on a layout manager to do this.

If you insist on doing it with a null layout, You will have to create your own JPanel subclass with a null layout manager, and in the paintComponent() method place the components yourself (or alternatively, write your own LayoutManager to do this).